# Fill missing column values depending on values in preceding row

Tags: r, fill

I have a huge table which basically looks like this:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F
A  B        &
A  B  C  D     $
A  B  C  @
```

The processed version should look like this:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F
A  B  B& B& B& B&
A  B  C  D  D$ D$
A  B  C  C@ C@ C@
```

The task is to concatenate value from the last non empty cell with the value from previous non empty cell (in same row) and use the new value to fill empty cells in that same row.

Any suggestions how to do this in **R**?

Comment: A reproducible example would be better (one that can be copy-pasted into R).

Comment: It's a fine question, but please consider adding some code that constructs a toy example. Maybe the one you are using for demonstration. Then answering would become much easier.

Comment: It's not clear why the last row should be filled with `"C@"`.

Comment: Do empty cells contain `" "` or `""`? Probably changes the solution if it either, both or neither.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to add the sample data to the post

Comment: Thanks everybody for tips, I will keep them in mind for future questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option that loops through the rows of the dataset.  We subset the elements of each row by selecting the elements that are not blank ('x1'), `paste` the last two non-blank elements in 'x1' together ('x2'), and then concatenate all the values except the last one (`head(x1,-1)`) with the 'x2' values that are replicated based on the number of columns of 'df1' and the `length` of 'x1'.  The result can be transposed (`t`) and converted to `data.frame`

```
 m1 <- t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
          x1 <- x[x!=''] #elements that are not-blank
          x2 <- paste(tail(x1,2), collapse='') #paste  the last two non-blank
          if(any(x=='')) #if there is any blank value
          c(head(x1,-1), rep(x2, ncol(df1)-length(x1)+1)) #concatenate
          else x #else return the row
           }))

 as.data.frame(m1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 #  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
 #1  A  B  C  D  E F
 #2  A  B B& B& B& B&
 #3  A  B  C  D D$ D$
 #4  A  B  C C@ C@ C@
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A"), v2 = c("B", "B", "B", 
 "B"), v3 = c("C", "", "C", "C"), v4 = c("D", "", "D", "@"), v5 = c("E", 
 "&", "", ""), v6 = c("F", "", "$", "")), .Names = c("v1", "v2", 
 "v3", "v4", "v5", "v6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Neat solution! Worked well.

Comment: Thanks for using **any()** in your answer - totally forgot about that one and it was perfect for checking if rows have empty cells.

Comment: @Iggy `any` and `all` are some convenient functions to use with `if` `else` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This problem screamed `na.locf` from `zoo`:

First, replace `""` to `NA`: `x[sapply(x,function(y)y=="X")]<-NA`

Strip symbols:

```
x.no.sym<-x
x.no.sym[sapply(x.no.sym,function(y)!y%in%LETTERS)]<-NA
```

Fill out the letters:

```
x.no.sym.fill<-t(apply(x.no.sym,1,na.locf))
     V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6 
[1,] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
[2,] "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
[3,] "A" "B" "C" "D" "D" "D"
[4,] "A" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C"
```

Now fill out the symbols and delete the letters:

```
x.sym.fill<-x.sym.fill<-t(apply(x,1,function(y)na.locf(na.locf(y,fromLast=T,na.rm=F),na.rm=F)))
x.sym.fill[sapply(x.sym.fill,function(y)y%in%LETTERS)]<-""
     V1 V2 V3  V4  V5  V6 
[1,] "" "" ""  ""  ""  "" 
[2,] "" "" "&" "&" "&" "&"
[3,] "" "" ""  ""  "$" "$"
[4,] "" "" ""  "@" "@" "@"
```

Now concatenate:

```
> matrix(paste0(x.no.sym.fill,x.sym.fill),ncol=ncol(x))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F" 
[2,] "A"  "B"  "B&" "B&" "B&" "B&"
[3,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "D$" "D$"
[4,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "C@" "C@" "C@"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one seems fun. I took blank spaces in the data frame to be `""` and called the data frame `df`.

```
fill = apply(df, 1, function(x) { 
  x = x[x != ""]
  paste(tail(x, 2), collapse = "")
})

df[df == ""] = matrix(fill, ncol = ncol(df), nrow = nrow(df))[df == ""]
```

Find for each row the unique filler value, make a matrix of the same structure as your original one of the fill values, then cherry pick the values you need to replace.

```
df = structure(list(A = c("A", "A", "A"), B = c("B", "B", "B"), C = c("", 
"C", "C"), D = c("", "D", "@"), E = c("&", "", ""), F = c("", 
"$", "")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```